# backtrack freezes when I connect to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, freeze, backtrack

I posted on stackoverflow a question [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744075/backtrack-5-wifi-freezing%20(link)) just go and read it, but basically, ~3 seconds after I connect to the wifi, everything freezes.  I can't do anything but hold down power to shut it down.

As an edit to the other post, I am now running a 64 bit version, installed to my hard drive set to dual boot with windows 8.  I tried installing kali (since backtrack is outdated and you can't register for their forums), but for some reason that didn't work, as everytime I booted it from my usb, it would just go black, and it would stay that way. (also no controls responding).  So really I am wondering how the heck can I make wifi work.  If I am not specific enough, I will take a video of exactly what is happening and post that in an edit.  If you need more info, I think I have that in the stackoverflow page, but if not, comment.

Apparently either my question is either too off topic for stackoverflow, or nobody cares.  Either way, somebody told me to come here and ask it.

I can also get ubuntu to work with wifi no problem, and backtrack is just a really modified version of ubuntu, so yah.

Comment: trying to keep it alive !!!(bump)  This same thing happened on the other site ! (silence)

Comment: We don't enjoy cross posting questions here at SE. It seems off topic for StackOverflow, so I would suggest having it migrated, or delete it yourself and update this question with the rest of the information from your other question. There's also no point in trying to bump a question, someone will help you out either when they're ready or when someone that *can* help you sees this.